# How to colour a SpatialLinesDataFrame with Rainbow

Tags: r, color

how to color a SpatialLinesDataFrame according to some given value (Rainbow)

```
FRA=readShapePoly("FRA_adm0.shp")
grid <- raster(extent(FRA))
# Choose its resolution. I will use 2 degrees of latitude and longitude.
res(grid) <- 0.3
# Transform this raster into a polygon and you will have a grid, but gwithout Brazil (or your own shapefile).
spdf <- rasterToPolygons(grid)
sldf <- as( spdf , "SpatialLinesDataFrame") # Create a lines object. This gives you the borders of the polygons
plot(sldf)
```

I have a set of [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdi7uqkwvot17xg/jsonallcoor.js?dl=0)  that I interpolate that I get a raster like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
require(rgeos)
library(rgdal) 
library(foreign)
library(maptools)
library(knitr)
library(jsonlite)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

#json data
dataJson <- fromJSON(readLines('/Users/macbook/Documents/mesdocument/exempleR/jsonallcoor.js'))
# shp
FRA=readShapePoly("/Users/macbook/Documents/mesdocument/exempleR/FRA_adm/FRA_adm0.shp")
#contour (interpolation idw)
x=data.frame(0)
y=data.frame(0)
t=data.frame(0)
for ( i in 1:103) { 
  x[i]<- as.data.frame.factor(dataJson[[i]]$longitude)# define x & y as longitude and latitude
  y[i]<- as.data.frame.factor(dataJson[[i]]$latitude)
  t[i]<- as.data.frame.factor(dataJson[[i]]$temperature)
}


x<- as.numeric(x) 
y <- as.numeric(y) 
temperature<- as.numeric(t)
frame=as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,temperature))
frame.xy = frame[c("x", "y")]
coordinates(frame.xy ) <- ~x+y
#Define the grid extent
x.range <- as.numeric(c(-4.445833,9.484722))  # min/max longitude of the interpolation area
y.range <- as.numeric(c(40.50306,51.2))  # min/max latitude of the interpolation area

#Create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or factors. See the description of the return value for precise details of the way this is done. Set spatial coordinates to create a Spatial object. Assign gridded structure:
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.1), 
                   y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 0.1)) 
# expand points to grid
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
#to pixel
gridded(grd) <- TRUE
#les lon et lat
points(frame.xy, pch =1, col = "black", cex = 0.1)
#Interpolate surface and fix the output
idw <- idw(formula = temperature ~ 1, locations = frame.xy, 
           newdata = grd)  # apply idw model for the data
residual_grid = raster(idw, "var1.pred")
proj4string(residual_grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # OSM Mercator projection


# Create an empty raster 
grid <- raster(extent(FRA))

# Choose its resolution. I will use 2 degrees of latitude and longitude.
res(grid) <- 0.2

# Make the grid have the same coordinate reference system (CRS) as the shapefile.
proj4string(grid)<-proj4string(FRA)
gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(grid)
library(leaflet)
# Initialisation 
m <- leaflet()
#m <- addTiles(leaflet())
m <- fitBounds(map = m, 
               lng1 = -4.445833,
               lat1 = 40.50306,
               lng2 = 9.484722, 
               lat2 =  50.56417)
pal <- colorNumeric(c("Spectral"), values(residual_grid),
                    na.color = "transparent")

m<-addRasterImage(map=m,residual_grid, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8)
m<-addLegend(map=m,pal = pal, values = values(residual_grid),
             title = "pression")
m<-addPolygons(map=m,data =gridpolygon,fillOpacity=1,opacity=1,smoothFactor = 1,fillColor = "transparent",
               color="#1874CD",weight=0.2)

## Dimensions de la carte
m$width <- 1000
m$height <-700

library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(m, '/Users/macbook/Documents/maps/contour.html', selfcontained = FALSE)
```

result like this:
[image]
Now I want spatial lines (grid) take raster colors. For that I searched and I found this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092358/r-rasterize-only-the-edges-of-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe) I applied like this:

```
sldf <- as( gridpolygon , "SpatialLinesDataFrame") # Create a lines object. This gives you the borders of the polygons
ra <- rasterize( sldf ,residual_grid )
```

result:
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just plot a SpatialLinesDataFrame in some colour scheme? Why do all that raster processing? What's that got to do with the title?

Comment: thanks for reply , I have to go through it to get the 'grid' (for another need), I want to color my grid according to some value

Comment: I try to do exactly example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092358/r-rasterize-only-the-edges-of-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe for my grid

Comment: but can we have this colorful grid without going through a raster?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  I notice that you have not yet taken the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce you to this site's protocols.

Comment: This q is perfectly clear IMO - the default sp plotting is very limited for thematic formatting - you can pass in cols to plot with the "col" argument, but you'll need to map the colour you to each rowin the spdf on your own. But, since the borders of each pixel are collinear you will get a complex pattern of colours based on incremental overlapping borders. Consider ggplot2::fortify(spdf) to go down another alternative for plotting. Make a new question or modify this one with more details about how you want the lines to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something as simple as this?

```
> FRAl = as(FRA,"SpatialLines")
> FRAp = as(FRAl, "SpatialPoints")
> FRAr = rasterize(FRAp, residual_grid, mask=TRUE)
> plot(FRAr)
```

[image]

The conversion to points before rasterisation should be unneccesary, I think `rasterize(FRAl,....)` should work, but is very slow on my machine. So slow I was too impatient to wait for it to finish. FRA has a lot of vertices which is probably why its (a) slow and (b) points work pretty well.

Note: please try and minimise your question. All that leaflet stuff is confusing and unnecessary. Also, all the `idw` calculation is unnecessary. Just create a raster with some random data and use that for examples rather than forcing us to download data sets and do all that setup code you've put in which is irrelevant to your actual problem, if I've understood correctly what your actual problem is...

Comment: thanks Spacedman, but I want rastariser grid lines (in the map) and not the outline of country

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear enough, I try to edit my question again

Comment: I want the grid takes the raster color values

Comment: Which grid? Which raster? You've got so many grids and rasters and polygons its just not clear. Why do you want the grid to take the raster values, why can't you just use the raster? Plus, rasters don't intrinsically **have** colours, they have values, possibly several, at each pixel. These are mapped to colours in some way when the thing is plotted.

Comment: hello, I would like to display more than one variable on the same map that's why I think working with the texture but apparently it does not work, thank you for your efforts..